# "Invalid signature" error in Iyzico payment integration with Laravel

Tags: php, e-commerce, payment, laravel-10

I am placing an e-commerce system with Laravel and [Iyzico](https://github.com/iyzico/iyzipay-php), but I am getting an invalid signature error, I don't know how to solve this, I have tried all kinds of methods, but the result is unsuccessful, I don't know if there is a problem with my codes, I would be very happy if you can help me, thanks in advance.

**Error:**
[image]

**Code:**

**Path:** app\Repositories\AppointmentRepository.php

```php
/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 */
public function store(AppointmentRequest $req): JsonResponse
{
    // dd($request->validated());
 
    try {
        $user = User::find(auth()->user()->id);
        $user = new UserResource($user);
 
        $data = $req->validated();
        $data['user_id'] =  $user->id;
        $data['conversation_id'] = $req->psychologist_id;
        $data['basket_id'] = 'OT#BASID' . Str::random(10);
        $data['buyer_id'] = $user->id;
        $data['registration_date'] = now();
        $data['card_save'] = $req->card_save ? 1 : 0;
        $data['invoice_full_name'] = $data['invoice_name'] . ' ' . $data['invoice_surname'];
        $data['ip_address'] = $req->ip();
 
        // Iyzico Payment Transactions
        $payment = $this->iyzicoPayment($data, $user);
 
       // dd($payment);
 
        if (isset($payment)) {
            return response()->json([
                'status' => [
                    'code' => Response::HTTP_CREATED,
                    'message' => 'Your appointment was successfully created.',
                ],
                'payment' => $payment,
            ], Response::HTTP_CREATED);
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        throw new ServerErrorException('appointment', $e);
    }
}
 
public function iyzicoPayment($data, $user): object
{
    $options = new \Iyzipay\Options();
    $options->setApiKey(config('services.iyzico.api_key'));
    $options->setSecretKey(config('services.iyzico.secret_key'));
    $options->setBaseUrl(config('services.iyzico.base_url'));
 
    $request = new \Iyzipay\Request\CreatePaymentRequest();
    $request->setLocale(\Iyzipay\Model\Locale::TR);
    // $request->setConversationId($data['conversation_id']);
    $request->setPrice("1");
    $request->setPaidPrice("1");
    $request->setCurrency(\Iyzipay\Model\Currency::TL);
    $request->setInstallment(1);
    $request->setBasketId($data['basket_id']);
    $request->setPaymentChannel(\Iyzipay\Model\PaymentChannel::WEB);
    $request->setPaymentGroup(\Iyzipay\Model\PaymentGroup::PRODUCT);
 
    $paymentCard = new \Iyzipay\Model\PaymentCard();
    $paymentCard->setCardHolderName($data['card_name']);
    $paymentCard->setCardNumber($data['card_number']);
    $paymentCard->setExpireMonth($data['card_month']);
    $paymentCard->setExpireYear($data['card_year']);
    $paymentCard->setCvc($data['card_cvv']);
    $paymentCard->setRegisterCard($data['card_save']);
    $request->setPaymentCard($paymentCard);
 
    $buyer = new \Iyzipay\Model\Buyer();
    $buyer->setId($data['buyer_id']);
    $buyer->setName($data['invoice_name']);
    $buyer->setSurname($data['invoice_surname']);
    $buyer->setGsmNumber($user->phone);
    $buyer->setEmail($user->email);
    $buyer->setIdentityNumber($user->identity_number);
    $buyer->setLastLoginDate($user->last_activity_at);
    $buyer->setRegistrationDate($data['registration_date']);
    $buyer->setRegistrationAddress($data['invoice_address']);
    $buyer->setIp($data['ip_address']);
    $buyer->setCity($data['invoice_city']);
    $buyer->setCountry("Turkey");
    $buyer->setZipCode($data['invoice_zipcode']);
    $request->setBuyer($buyer);
 
    $shippingAddress = new \Iyzipay\Model\Address();
    $shippingAddress->setContactName($data['invoice_full_name']);
    $shippingAddress->setCity($data['invoice_city']);
    $shippingAddress->setCountry("Turkey");
    $shippingAddress->setAddress($data['invoice_address']);
    $shippingAddress->setZipCode($data['invoice_zipcode']);
    $request->setShippingAddress($shippingAddress);
 
    $billingAddress = new \Iyzipay\Model\Address();
    $billingAddress->setContactName($data['invoice_full_name']);
    $billingAddress->setCity($data['invoice_city']);
    $billingAddress->setCountry("Turkey");
    $billingAddress->setAddress($data['invoice_address']);
    $billingAddress->setZipCode($data['invoice_zipcode']);
    $request->setBillingAddress($billingAddress);
 
    $basketItems = array();
    $firstBasketItem = new \Iyzipay\Model\BasketItem();
    $firstBasketItem->setId($data['basket_id']);
    $firstBasketItem->setName("OT Session");
    $firstBasketItem->setCategory1("Session Package");
    $firstBasketItem->setItemType(\Iyzipay\Model\BasketItemType::VIRTUAL);
    $firstBasketItem->setPrice($data['invoice_pricing']);
    $basketItems[0] = $firstBasketItem;
    $request->setBasketItems($basketItems);
 
    return \Iyzipay\Model\Payment::create($request, $options);
}
```

**Path:** app\Http\Controllers\Panel\AppointmentController.php

```php
/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 */
public function store(AppointmentRequest $request): RedirectResponse
{
    $data = ConvertHelper::jsonToView($this->appointmentRepository->store($request));

    return redirect()->route('panel.appointments.for-client')->with(['status' => $data->status]);
}
```

I want to make a payment using the payment method with [Iyzico](https://github.com/iyzico/iyzipay-php) and skip to the next step if the transaction is successful...

If my method is wrong you can show an example with laravel 10.x version update from scratch!

Comment: Your screenshot appears to show a dump of the Payment instance itself, and not actually a caught exception?

Comment: This is the response I got back... Here is the "status" in the response: "success" instead of "failure". I think I'm making a mistake somewhere but I can't find the problem. I don't know if it's because of the version work.

Despite the recommended configuration settings of the Iyzico payment system, it is constantly stuck on this error.

Comment: I can't tell what you are trying to say there. If the `status` which used to be `failure`, actually _is_ `success` now - then everything is working now, or - what ...?